# Can't install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer for a .NET 4.7.2 Framework project

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget

I have a VB.NET Windows Forms project targeting the .NET Framework 4.7.2:

[image]

I am trying to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` of which the latest stable version is 5.0.8:

[image]

However after clicking install and accepting all terms I get an error:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 5.0.8'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Does anyone know what the heck its moaning about version for?

Comment: Read the error again. It explains clearly what's wrong. You can't install a .NET Core package into a .NET Old project.  If you want to use EF Core, you have to upgrade to .NET Core 3.1 at least, if not .NET (Core) 5, to get full support for WinForms. Otherwise use EF 6.4 or EF Core 3.1, the last EF Core version that supported .NET Framework

Comment: When I check my .Net Core Version (cmd dotnet --version) then it states 3.1.411. Are you suggesting I upgrade to .NET 5.0

Comment: The "dotnet --version" just tells you what .NET Core version is on your machine - but your **project** in Visual Studio also **must be .NET Core** in order for it to reference Entity Framework Core .....

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, I created a class project separate from my forms project.

Comment: ANd is that really a **.NET Core** project? If so, you should be able to reference Entity Framework Core from it.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know what the heck its moaning about version for?

[image]

EF Core 5 requires .NET Standard 2.1.  .NET Framework only [supports .NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#latest-versions).  So it will never work.

EF Core 3.1 is the last version to support .NET Standard 2.0, and so it's the last version of EF Core compatible with .NET Framework.

But .NET Core 5 supports [Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/overview/?view=netdesktop-5.0).

So the options are:

- upgrade everything to .NET Core 5
- <strike>downgrade EF Core to version 3.1</strike>
- switch from EF Core to EF 6, which is mature, stable and supports .NET Framework

Comment: Thank you very much! :D Downgraded to 3.1.32 and it worked for me.